# How can I narrow down the results of a scrape with beautifulsoup + requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My code's function is to read a list of URLS on an xlxs sheet (i.e stackoverflow.com).

It then goes to stackoverflow.com and checks to see if there is an Instagram account linked on the home page, if so it returns the link to that and writes it in the adjacent column.

However, some sites will have it listed in multiple places, header, footer or have a feed which will return multiple results to the cell.

Is there a way to return just a single result?

```py
for cell in sheet[col][1:]:
    try:
        url = cell.value
        r = requests.get(url)
        ig_get = ['instagram.com']
        ig_get_present = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
        all_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
        print(cell.value)
        for ig_get in ig_get:
            for link in all_links:
                if ig_get in link.attrs['href']:
                    ig_get_present.append(link.attrs['href'])
                    ig_got = str(ig_get_present)
                    print(ig_got)
                    sheet.cell(cell.row, col2).value = ig_got
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        pass
```

**Edit for clarity:**

Some domains will have multiple links to their social media pages, i.e one in the header, one in the footer, one in the navigation bar etc OR a mirror of their social media feed. In these cases, I am outputted with multiple of the same link in the cell:

```
['https://instagram.com/xxx', 'https://instagram.com/xxx', 'https://instagram.com/xxx']
```

I would only want one of these, not all of them.

Comment: Do you mean a single result per domain or just 1 result period....

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified, a single per domain

Comment: I've updated the question to add clarity and show an example of the output I receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to only input the first match into the cell then all you really need is a break statement placed immediately after the first match.

For example:

```py
...
...
url = cell.value
res = requests.get(url)
domain = 'instagram.com'
urls = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html5lib')
all_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for link in all_links:
    if domain in link['href']:
        url = link['href']
        urls.append(url)
        sheet.cell(cell.row, col2).value = url
        break
...
...
```

The `break` statement in python is a control flow statement that immediately breaks you out of whatever loop your code is executing.

You can read more about it in the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Perfect that worked, thank you. I will look into break statements to get an understanding of how they work :)

Comment: @Kal-Toh  I added a quick summary to my answer of the break statement and a link to their description in the python docs... I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way would be to use an css attribute selector with contains (*) operator, specify the domain that should be found, use select_one to return the first match only

```
domain = 'instagram.com'
soup.select_one(f'a[href*="{domain}"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

another option other than scraping each website is to use google dorks and let google do the work for you

google dorks are like specific queries that narrows down the search for you

since some websites will link their instagram username on a different page than homepage the approach above wont work in this case however if you do a google search in this format

```
Site:stackoverflow.com intext:"https://www.instagram.com/"
```

google will return all pages containing https://www.instagram.com/ in its text relating to that specific website